# Orthogonal projection.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have found this question in a book, but I don't know how to use that $\left\Vert P\right\Vert =1$.

Question:
If $P\in\mathcal{L}(H)$ is a projection and $\left\Vert P\right\Vert =1$, show that $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

Where $\mathcal{L}(H)$ is the set of linear bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$.

Thanks.

Comment: [It's a classical exercise](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/415426/38053).

Comment: @AndrésFelipeTéllezCrespo: Suggestion: to get good answers, why don't you explain first what have you done so far to try to solve the problem? Did you write down the definition of orthogonal projection?