# Show that $P$ is normal if and only if it is an orthogonal projection.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex inner product space, and $P$ be a projection. Show that
$P$ is normal if and only if it is an orthogonal projection.

---

My work:

For the statement "*$P$ is normal implies it is an orthogonal projection*", we need to show that for all $u, v$,
$$
\langle Pu, v\rangle =\langle u, Pv\rangle 
$$

But we only know that $P^2=P$ and $P^*P=PP^*$. How to prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume that $P\neq 0.$ If $P^2=P$ then $(P^*)^2=P^*.$
The matrix $PP^*$ is also a projection as
$$(P^*P)^2=P^*PP^*P=(P^*)^2P^2=P^*P.$$
Moreover $P^*P$ is orthogonal, hence $\|P^*P\|=1.$ Thus $$\|P\|^2=\|P^*P\|=1$$ i.e. $\|P\|=1.$
It is well known that a contractive projection is orthogonal, therefore $P$ is orthogonal ([see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415426/prove-that-t-is-an-orthogonal-projection))

Answer (score 1):

By the spectral theorem the matrix of the transformation with respect to some orthonormal basis is diagonal. Because the transformation is a projection the square of the matrix is equal to itself. Therefore, the entries on the diagonal are either 0 or 1, which is the matrix of an orthogonal projection.