# Orthogonal projection: more linear algebra questions

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on proving the following:

If $P:V\to V$ is a linear operator and $P^2=P$ and $\|Pv\|\le\|v\|$ for all $v \in V$ then $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

My thoughts on this are that a linear map with the following properties is an orhtogonal projection: $null(P) $ is the orthogonal complement of its range, $P^2 = P$ and $\|Pv\|\le\|v\|$.

Therefore it should be enough to show that the range of $P$ is orthogonal to its null space. How to do this? Let $n \in null(P)$ and $u \in range(P) = U$. Want to show: $\langle u,n \rangle = 0$.

Am I doing this right? And how can I show $\langle u,n \rangle = 0$?

Comment: First $P$ is a projection because of $P^2=P$. Then you can see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97004/a-projection-satisfying-px-leq-x-for-all-x-is-an-orthogonal-proje?rq=1).

Comment: Right, what you link to is an alternative proof of what I am trying to prove. But I don't see how it answers either of my two questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u\in range(P)$ and $n\in null(P)$. If $u$ and $n$ are not orthogonal, then we have some scalar $c$ such that $\|u+cn\|<\|u\|$. But $P(u+cn)=Pu=u$ and so $\|P(u+cn)\|>\|u+cn\|$, contradicting your assumption.

Comment: How do you get a scalar $c$ such that $\|u + cn\|< \|u\|$? I can only get $\|u + cn\| \le \|u\|$

Comment: @newb We have $$\|u+cn\|^2=\langle u+cn,u+cn\rangle = \langle u,u\rangle + 2c\langle u,n\rangle + c^2\langle n,n\rangle = \|u\|^2+2c\langle u,n\rangle + c^2\|n\|^2$$ which has derivative with respect to $c$ at $c=0$ equal to $2\langle u,n\rangle\ne 0$. If this is positive then for small negative $c$ we have $\|u+cn\|<\|u\|$, while if this is negative then for small positive $c$ we have $\|u+cn\|<\|u\|$.